# Improve the copy activities performance on Azure Data Factory V2

Tags: azure

I have a pipeline in ADF to copy 18 tables from source to destination. Noticed that the copy performance on ADF is taking too long, like 12 hours. But when we performed the same using SSIS it's took only like 2 hours. I noticed the copy activity is static when it is almost at completion. Does anyone faces the same issue?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAl0p.png)